# How do we prove that the interval $[-1, 1]$ is closed under multiplication?

Tags: real-analysis

I tried to use the concept of absolute values given two elements. The product of the two absolute values would then be greater than or equal to zero. I know intuitively that it is closed under multiplication, however, I do not know how to prove it is.

Comment: What tools do you have in order to prove this result?  What theorems or definitions do you know?  What is the context in which this problem was posed?

Comment: If one of the answers below answered your question, the way this site works works, you'd "accept" the answer, more here: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). But only if your question really has been answered. If not, consider adding more details to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use$$x \in [-1,1] \iff |x| \le 1$$

Suppose $x,y \in [-1,1]$. Then $|x|,|y| \le 1$.

Hence $|xy| = |x||y| \le 1 \times 1 = 1$.

This shows that $xy \in [-1,1]$, and hence $[-1,1]$ is closed under multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x,y\in[-1,1]$. Then $-1\le x\le 1$. If $y=0$ then $xy=0\in[-1,1]$. If $0<y\le 1$ then $-1\le -y<0$ and multiplying $y$ in the inequality we get $-1\le -y\le xy\le y\le1$. If $-1\le y<0$ then $0<-y\le 1$ and multiplying $y$ in the inequality we get $1\ge-y\ge xy\ge y\ge 1$.